# Are questions about archeological or geological facts on-topic here?

Tags: support

Most of the times as in the Help Center tells, on-topic stuff is about human-related facts, say: cultures, languages, famous people, political-related, human prehistory. Meanwhile, the item *Historical Facts* makes me think about stuff mankind has somehow recorded.

If I interpreted it right, stuff like asking about archeological facts/findings does not seem to be on-topic.

Up to what extend am I right or wrong about what I said? Is this the place to ask, say, the archeological or geological facts about something which is not a priori related with human behavior? Or should I ask about those when human-related facts had place?

Comment: In my experience archeological (and to a lesser extent, geological) topics are acceptable so long as they are relevant to the study of history in the time frame in which humans have lived on the Earth. Anything else geological would be on topic at [Earth Science](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

If there were no people, or even Hominids, around when said event took place (or it didn't affect the ones that were in the slightest), then the question is definitely off-topic as "General (non-human) Prehistory". That would include almost all questions chiefly involving Geology or Astrophysics.

In addition, the "Human Prehistory" bullet on the "*can* I ask here" section is fairly new and doesn't exactly have 100% buy-in at the moment. If you ask such a question, I'd highly suggest phrasing and proofreading it carefully.

The "historical facts" entry is very old, and could perhaps get massaged a bit. I believe the emphasis is supposed to be on the word "facts", as opposed to its opposite "opinions". IOW, its OK to ask what countries Genghis Khan invaded, but it would be very shaky ground to ask which countries we as posters think he preferred.

The basic one-phrase description of this stack's scope is "The Story of Humanity", not "Everything that happened in the past, ever."<sup>*</sup>

<sup>* - ...but also not "everything that can be figured out about the past only by reading old books".</sup>